# How to join the new value with existing database value using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to join one new value with existing value present inside database column using PHP and Mysql.I am explaining my table below.

> db_admin

```
id    supplier_id

1      2,3,4,5,6
```

Here in `supplier_id` column i have some value like `2,3,4,5,6`.suppose i need to add another value lets say `7` with the existing `supplier_id` with comma operator finally the result will be `2,3,4,5,6,7` So i need query for that.Please help me.

Comment: `update db_admin set supplier_id=concat(supplier_id, ',7');`

Comment: Fix your data structure to have a proper junction table (one row per id and supplier_id).  Then use `insert`.

Comment: Normalize your database to 1NF and you can do this easily. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity for why your design isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use Following query using Concat

```
UPDATE `db_admin` SET `supplier_id` = concat(supplier_id, ',7') WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff stated you shouldn't try to handle it in this manner. Make a proper linking table between this table and the supplier table.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

You can add the 7 now, but tomorrow you want to remove the 4 and then you have a new problem.